# Producing avro message using php-enqueue

Tags: php, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, php-enqueue

I'm researching a way of producing avro messages from php to kafka using [php-enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev).

Their [documentation](https://php-enqueue.github.io/transport/kafka/)  states that you can use other formats, including Apache Avro.

> By default the transport serializes messages to json format but you
> might want to use another format such as Apache Avro. For that you
> have to implement Serializer interface and set it to the context,
> producer or consumer. If a serializer set to context it will be
> injected to all consumers and producers created by the context.
>
> ```
> <?php
> use Enqueue\RdKafka\Serializer;
> use Enqueue\RdKafka\RdKafkaMessage;
>
> class FooSerializer implements Serializer
> {
>     public function toMessage($string) {}
>
>     public function toString(RdKafkaMessage $message) {}
> }
>
> /** @var \Enqueue\RdKafka\RdKafkaContext $context */
>
> $context->setSerializer(new FooSerializer());
> ```

The serializer in the example is converting to and from strings. Avro format is binary as far as I understand, so how is a custom serializer supposed to work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php strings can contain binary data. Here's a partial implementation of producing an avro message using a schema id that had been registered in schema registry.
The serialization to avro is done using [jaumo/avro](https://gitlab.com/Jaumo/avro-php) implementation.

```
public function toString(RdKafkaMessage $message): string
{
    ...

    $message = json_decode($message->getBody(), true);

    $encodedHeader = $this->createAvroHeader($schemaId);
    $encodedMessage = Serde::encodeMessage($parsedSchema, $message);

    return $encodedHeader . $encodedMessage;
}

private function createAvroHeader(int $schemaId): string
{
    $binarySchemaId = hex2bin(sprintf("%08s", dechex($schemaId)));
    return pack("C", 0) . $binarySchemaId;
}
```